# Fetch data from a nested api link

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, router

I have an API that provide other API link in an Array, I am able to fetch data from the first level of the Array but I also want to fetch data from the API that is inside the other Array. E.g The characters Array how can I get data inside the API?

The below is for a detail page.
API link https://swapi.dev/api/films/1

```
<template>
  <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
          <div class="movie__content-wrap content">
            <template v-if="movie">
            <h1 class="movie__card-title card-title text-center">{{ movie.title }}</h1>
              <div class="meta mt-5 mb-5">
                <p class="mb-0"><strong>Episode: </strong>{{ movie.episode_id }}</p>
                <p class="mb-0"><strong>Release date:</strong>{{ movie.release_date }}</p>
                <p class="mb-0"><strong>Characters: </strong>{{ movie.characters }}</p>
              </div>
              <p class="mt-4 mb-5">{{ movie.opening_crawl }}</p>
            </template>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: 'MovieDetails',
  props: 
  {
    id: String,
  },
  data(){
    return {
      movie: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('https://swapi.dev/api/films/'+this.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.movie = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch data for the characters, you need to make additional API requests to the character URLs and collect the data. Here's how you can do it:

**First, modify your movie object to include an array for character
data. Initialize it as an empty array:**

```
data() {
  return {
    movie: {
      charactersData: [],
    }
  }
},
```

**In your mounted hook, after fetching movie data, you can make additional requests to fetch character data:**

```
mounted() {
  axios.get('https://swapi.dev/api/films/' + this.id)
    .then(response => {
      this.movie = response.data;

      // Fetch character data for each character URL
      const characterPromises = this.movie.characters.map(characterUrl => axios.get(characterUrl));

      // Wait for all character data requests to complete
      Promise.all(characterPromises)
        .then(characterResponses => {
          this.movie.charactersData = characterResponses.map(response => response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
},
```

**Now, you can use movie.charactersData in your template to display character information:**

```
<p class="mb-0"><strong>Characters:</strong>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="character in movie.charactersData" :key="character.url">
      {{ character.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

With these changes, you'll fetch data for each character URL inside the `movie.characters` array and store it in `movie.charactersData`. Then, you can iterate through `movie.charactersData` to display character names in your template.

Comment: Thanks @Jeevan, it worked, now I feel like my movie request will have many nested request as I will have to do the same for other nested request e.g vehicles, species etc. If I have to create a component for each. Do you think it will work?

Comment: @NeronGodfather - yeah, it is organized way to handle multiple nested requests in your application and it will make your code more maintainable and easier to understand! All the best!